# Apache Spark: Reduce number of cores during an execution

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to reduce the number of cores / executors during a certain part of the run.  We don't want to overrun the end datastore, but need more cores to do computational work effectively.

Basically

```
// want n cores here
val eventJsonRdd: RDD[(String,(Event, Option[Article]))] = eventGeoRdd.leftOuterJoin(articlesRdd)

val toSave =  eventJsonRdd.map(processEventsAndArticlesJson)

// want two cores here
toSave.saveToEs("apollobit/events")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
toSave.repartition(2).saveTo...
```

Although this will entail a potentially expensive shuffle.

If your store supports bulk updates, you will get way better performance by calling `foreachPartition` and doing something with a chunk of data rather than one at a time.

Comment: What would the syntax be for the foreachPartition?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
Something like ... .foreachPartition { iterator => saveThemAll(iterator) }

Comment: Sean, I believe `.coalesce(2)` will do the same but minimize any shuffling where possible.

Comment: or `.repartition(numPartitions=2, shuffle=false)`, for which `.colesce(numPartitions=2)` is an alias.

Comment: Since I cannot edit the comment. .coalesce(numPartitions=2) ... typo spelling the crazy word coalesce